# How to fetch certain column data from datasource?

Tags: google-app-maker

I want to fetch the specified column from a data source(i.e. exclude certain columns) because even I don't show the data in UI, the data is loaded. (it is visible from Network tabs in Browser DevTools).

So far, I found the automatic data load and query builder/ query script provide the filters and sorting of the data but loads all the columns.

I have tried record owner security and role based security but this will make the data inaccessible to some users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try creating a Calculated SQL Model to limit columns being pulled.

Let's take an example where you have a Student model with Name and City as the only two fields. You can add a new Calculated SQL with this SQL query and only Name column would be pulled.

```
SELECT Name FROM Student
```

Please refer to the official guide [here](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/models/cloudsql#calculated_sql_models). Feel free to comment if you want some clarification!

Hope this helps.

Comment: ```A SQL calculated model uses a Cloud SQL query to retrieve data. Like other calculated datasources, a SQL datasource can't create, delete, or update records.```

Question 1: How do I insert to the table? Is it from a spreadsheet at time of initialization?

Question 2: Does the calculated model limit column from its own fields or other models too(Something like join)?

Sorry for the poor research[Desparate times :( ]

Comment: Sorry for the late reply! A calculated SQL is just a virtual table that uses several tables to create a sort of a view. You don't have to insert any data in a calculated SQL model. You would insert data in the tables that the calculated SQL model uses and that would be enough. Please let me know, am I able to make sense?

Comment: I am accepting your answer. However, for the requirement like getting specific columns and being able to update those columns only, SQL calculated model would not be the ideal solution to go with.